# Slick Slider responsive

Tags: slider, responsive, slick.js

Проблема в следующем:
заходим сюда  http://www.mitrix.io/mobile-development
на середине странице чёрная секция "Our Domains of Expertise"
там заголовок и 8 элементов l-dedicated-developers__item
так воооот:   на десктопе должно выглядеть так как есть сейчас, на размере width: 830 px  список преобразуется в скрол по X, а хотелось бы в слайдер с swipe эффектом, а при возвращении в разрешение с шириной больше width 830px снова должен быть обычный список.

Использую Slick slider,  и не могу понять как заставить его инициализироваться без перезапуска страницы, а от ресайза окна.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(window).on('load resize orientationchange', function () {

  $('.js-slider').each(function () {
    var $carousel = $(this);

    if ($(window).width() > 830) {

      if ($carousel.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $carousel.slick('unslick');
      }

    } else {

      if (!$carousel.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
        $carousel.slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          mobileFirst: true,
        });
      }

    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container__row {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 50%;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container js-slider">
  <div class="container__row js-slider">
    <div class="block block1">A</div>
    <div class="block block2">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```